# Parse - PFObject - property

Tags: ios, parsing, object, properties, subclass

How can I get the values of createdAt, updatedAt by method?

```
PFObject gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"]; 
NSString playerName = gameScore[@"playerName"];
```

And instead of doing this:

```
NSDate updatedAt = gameScore.updatedAt; 
NSDate createdAt = gameScore.createdAt;
```

Do like the I did in the playerName:

```
NSDate *updatedAt = gameScore[@"updatedAt"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`updateAt` is a property of `PFObject`. Let `object` is an instance of `PFObject`. Just do this:

```
NSDate *updated = [object updatedAt];
```

[See here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html) for more info.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Since it's a property you can also use dot notation (`object.updatedAt`).

Answer (score 0):

But I don't have the PFObject in that case! 
I'm doing a query to take the values of my class 'boteco', and I'm adding pin with informations to my mapView

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"boteco"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            mapArray = [objects copy];
            for (int i=0; i<objects.count; i++)
            {
                latitude = [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
                longitude = [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
                nome = [[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"nome"];
                // I want here to take the value of "updatedAt" ex: uptadedAt=[[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"updatedAt"];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = { latitude, longitude };
                DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
                ann.coordinate = coord;
                [mapview addAnnotation:ann];
            }
        }
```